# Inconsistent results with QUnit

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I want to use the QUnit Framework to test my application. I am testing simple code with two tests.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.1.css">
</head>
<body >
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.1.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
*** FIRST :

QUnit.test( "Test 1",      function(assert) {
                  assert.ok(1==1);      }   );
QUnit.test( "Test 2",      function(assert) {
        assert.ok( 3 == 3);      }  );

*** CHANGED : This test produces a similar result to the previous.

QUnit.test( "Test 1",      function(assert) {
                  assert.ok(1==1);      }   );
QUnit.test( "Test 2",      function(assert) {
        assert.ok( '3' == '1');      }  );
```

When I run these the first time, it works. But if I go back to the code and I change the condition, save, and press F5 (refresh) in the browser (chrome 52), the result becomes inconsistent. In both cases the result is the same. Sometimes it is updated, other times it is not updated!?! Is there any special configuration that is required? (.json, .ini) Has someone already resolved this situation? Grateful.

Comment: So, how is this question related to PHP?

Comment: Please show the results that occur after running each test scenario.

Comment: Unless you can show us the results you're seeing I'm not sure we can help... but this could just be a browser caching issue.